# Python version of 'pcsegdist' in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am trying to find python version of pcsegdist function. It segments point cloud based on euclidean distance.

I have applied dbscan in python (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html).

I have set the minPoints parameter same in both functions.
I have set the Eps parameter in python and minDistance parameter in matlab  same.

The 'eps parameter' means that if the distance between two points is lower or equal to this value (eps), these points are considered neighbors. (https://towardsdatascience.com/how-dbscan-works-and-why-should-i-use-it-443b4a191c80)
The  'minDistance parameter'  is the minimum Euclidean distance between points from two different clusters, specified as a positive scalar.

Hence I set both minDistance and eps parameter same.

But the output number of clusters are different from matlab and python functions when they are applied on same point cloud.
Any answer on this question would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to find a function with the exact same implementation (might be difficult). Easier is probably to call the Python function from within MATLAB, see [this documentation page](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-python-libraries.html) on why.

Comment: Thanks! Python would be my preference as I am working on a deep learning pipeline and its modules are in python. This clustering was performed in matlab on a segmentation result from a neural network.

Comment: I'm wondering how close [sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html) could be by specifying `distance_threshold`.

Comment: The other way around (calling MATLAB from Python) also works of course. Problem there is, that you'll need to have a working MATLAB license to be able to run the program. In that case, it'd be better to use a full Python implementation probably.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I can try that.

Comment: @Adriaan This seems better. Thanks